# Custom category template WP

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom post type (activity) with category taxonomy , In the menu the user can select which category he want to display , the problem is that I created category.php but nothing appears on my site here is the code :

```
<h1><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
                <?php if (is_category('edition')) : 
                     $args = array('category_name' => 'edition');  
                else : 
                     $args = array('category_name' => 'diffusion'); 
                endif; ?>

                <?php $query1 = new WP_Query( $args ); 
                if ( $query1->have_posts() ) {
                    while ( $query1->have_posts() ) {
                            $query1->the_post();
                            echo '<p>' . get_the_title() . '</p>';
                    }
                }
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call your file archive-activity.php to make it work .

For your custom post type it's archive-{post-type}.php, and keep the same code you've posted.

The archive-{post-type}.php template provides the most general form of control, providing a layout for custom post type archives, a page that displays a list of posts.

To use different template for your special taxonomy create a file call taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php or tag-{slug}.php to target specific term.

You can read more about the template hierarchy here : [custom-post-type-template-files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/)

Comment: thanks for your answer.it means that I have to create many files as much as the number of categories that I have, because I tried to change the name of category.php to archive.php but it doesn't work